# Prove that $2^n-3$ is squarefree

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be a natural number with $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Is it true that $2^n-3$ is not divisible by $p^2$ for any prime $p$?

I am conjecturing the above to be true, so I was wondering if there were any counterexamples to it since I checked it up to $n = 101$ and it was true up to then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$2^{481}-3$ (or more generally $2^{684t-203}-3$ for any integer $t$) is divisible by $19^2$.

Comment: Your answer is fine now, I upvoted.